# Main storyboard cannot be found?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface

I am a new IOS person.
   I just meet with a situation, and I cannot figure out why. Really appreciate it if anyone can give some suggestions.

My problem is pretty similar to this guy's problem:
   [IOS-Convert code-based interface to Storyboard based interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464331/ios-convert-code-based-interface-to-storyboard-based-interface)

and my console info is :

```
 * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle (loaded)' 
* First throw call stack: (0x184c2a530 0x195bac0e4 0x189a04484 0x1896c4590 
0x1896c3728 0x1896c1f1c 0x18d0f1604 0x184be2d70 0x184be1e78 0x184be0078 
0x184b0d1f4 0x1894a3020 0x18949e10c 0x10005fd68 0x19622aa08) libc++abi.dylib: 
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
```

Comment: And I have added the storyboard name into plist, but it still does not work.    still give me thread 1: signal SIGABRT error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you name the storyboard, Main?  My advice is to create a new project, and compare the Info.plist of the current project with the new one.

If you want the app to open the storyboard, it should be added to the line:

```
    Main storyboard file base name
```

From the source code it would be:
            UIMainStoryboardFile
            Main

Sample Info.plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.bulenapps.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
        <array>
            <string>armv7</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: Thanks man, already found a solution!~Tanks anyway!  I just checked the target in the storyboard  Membership

Answer (score 0):

Please edit appDelegate.m File in didFinishLaunch Method and try this one..

_serialManager = [[RscMgr alloc] init];

DetectionViewModel* detectionViewModel = [[DetectionViewModel alloc]   initWithSerialManager: _serialManager];

UIStoryboard * aStoryBorad=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

_viewController = aStoryBorad instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"_viewController"];

Thanks
Regards
Hemant

Comment: Thanks!!!       problems has been fixed, I just make the storyboard 's target be checked in his target membership